# Check amount of 'overlap' of two sides of adjacent rectangles

Tags: javascript, overlap

I have two rectangles that are guaranteed not to overlap.

However, I need to know if they are next to each other and if they are that they touch each other by two or more units. For example, the following rectangles touch at 4 units.

[image]

In the above example I am comparing the following:

```
rect1 = {
   x: 4,
   y: 4,
   width: 3,
   height: 5
}
```

and

```
rect2 = {
   x: 7,
   y: 1,
   width: 4,
   height: 7
}
```

I am currently trying to accomplish this by several nested if/else statements, but I know there would be a more adequate way.

What is an efficient way of accomplishing this?

**Disclaimer:**

I used the term `overlap` in the title as I wasn't sure how else to describe it even though they do not actually overlap.

Comment: You can do a check like this  a.x  > (b.x + b.w) ||  (a.x + a.w) <  b.x  ||  a.y > (b.y +b.h) ||(a.y + a.h) <  b.y); Just compair the two

Comment: the term you want to be using is "adjacent": you want to know whether two rectangles are adjacent, and if so, if the adjacency covers two or more units. Having said that, if you already have working code, and you want to know how to improve it, SO is not the place to ask. Instead, you want https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Frankly, I think a bunch of IF statements will be the most efficient way. You only compare a few numbers, some addition, and that's it. No memory allocations, no function calls, no nothing. I'd go with IFs.

Comment: @StefanAvramovic What exactly is your code doing? It looks more like code for checking for overlapping objects.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Not quite working yet. I was hacking away at it and getting confused with all the nesting that I realized I should just check to see if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: @Vilx- is certainly right, the IF statements are certainly the most efficient way to go. Still fun to look at it from another angle :)

Comment: @kojow7 thats the concept if you add a bit to it it will work fine, for example a.w + 1  and check for overlap if hitt its adjacent

Comment: Accept an answer maybe? :) The top-voted one seems the best to me! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple version:

```
function rectOverlaps2(r1, r2) {
    let overlapX, overlapY;

    if ( r1.x <= r2.x ) {
        overlapX = r1.x + r1.width - r2.x;
    } else {
        overlapX = r2.x + r2.width - r1.x;
    }

    if ( r1.y <= r2.y ) {
        overlapY = r1.y + r1.height - r2.y;
    } else {
        overlapY = r2.y + r2.height - r1.y;
    }

    return (overlapX == 0 && overlapY >= 2) || (overlapY == 0 && overlapX >= 2);
}
```

**Added:** Just realized that there is an edge case - if the overlapping dimension (width or height) of one rectangle is just 1 unit, then the overlap should not be counted. Since this looks like a homework question, fixing this will be left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: No, not a homework question. Still need to work through your code, but I thought that the `overlapY >= 2` was taking into account the edge case.

Comment: @kojow7 - no, that's just the distance between the edges of the two rectangles. Imagine a very large (100x100) rectangle touching a small (1x1) rectangle right in the middle. `OverlapY` would be something like `50`, yet the touching area would still be just 1 square.

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution for this problem. My idea is to create an array that contains all numbers between the start of the rectangle and its end in the Y direction, for example. Then if the other rectangle contains any of the indices in between, that means they are 'overlapping'

I didn't try any performance optimization, but that's the general idea.

```
rect1 = {
   x: 4,
   y: 4,
   width: 3,
   height: 5
}

rect2 = {
   x: 7,
   y: 1,
   width: 4,
   height: 7
}


function createMap(start, end) {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
}

function getEndPoints(rect){
  const endX = rect.x + rect.width;
  const endY = rect.y + rect.height;
  return {endX, endY}; 
}

function getOverlap(r1, r2){
  const r1Range = createMap(r1.y, r1.endY);
  const r2Range = createMap(r2.y, r2.endY);
  const verticalOverlap = r1Range.filter(val => !r2Range.includes(val));
  console.log(`These two rectangles overlap by: ${verticalOverlap.length} squares`)
  // Then just do the same for horizontal
}

rect1 = {...rect1, getEndpoints(rect1)}
rect2 = {...rect2, getEndpoints(rect2)}

getOverlap(rect1, rect2);
```